# How to Change @resource confirmation_url on Devise Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to change this resource

```
<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %> </p>
```

I don't need redirect to the token path, I need simply redirect to root_path after the user has confirmed the email

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise has a lot of functionality that is inherently built in.

in order to change how it behaves you must implicitly override its behaviour or modify it in some way.

in this case you want to have a Confirmations controller that inherits from devise conf contr. inside there you want to

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController

# some other code if you want to change how certain views behave 


private

def after_confirmation_path_for(resource)
  sign_in(resource) # signs in the user at confirmation


  # does whatever you want after the user is singed in at the confirmation 
  # - this is where you may want to redirect or whatever you desire
  after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 
end

end
```

Define the after_sign_in_path_for in the application controller

you can do something like:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 root_path
end
```

This should get you started, check the devise docs as they are pretty solid.

Comment: No worries Daniel, if you found the answer helpful, please let others know by marking it as the accepted/correct answer.

Cheers